# OpenAPI Dart generator

Tags: dart, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm using OpenAPI generator to generate Dart client to my spec.

One of my endpoints returns binary data which reflects in schema like this:

```
"responses" : {
  "200" : {
    "description" : "",
    "content" : {
      "application/octet-stream" : {
        "schema" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "format" : "binary"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Client is generated without errors, with the response type Future. However  when I invoke that method, I get error like this:

```
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
  
#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1404:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1271:9)
#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:936:22)
#3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10)
#4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:506:36)
#5      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:157:41)
#6      jsonDecode (dart:convert/json.dart:96:10)
#7      ApiClient.deserialize (package:openapi/api_client.dart:192:20)
#8      DefaultApi.testIntPost (package:openapi/api/default_api.dart:143:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      main.<anonymous closure> (package:X/run.dart)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the dart-dio generator and it worked OK with binary return type. Still I will not mark this answer as the right one since the question regarding dart generator is not solved